# Can I slice a sentence while ignoring whitespaces?

Tags: python

Like the title says, can I slice a sentence while ignoring whitespaces in Python?

For example, if the last letter of my word is sliced, the second letter of the following word needs to be sliced (while I'm using `[::2]`). I also have to preserve punctuations, so split isn't really an option. Replacing whitespaces isn't an option either, because I would have no way to put them back in the correct spot.

Sample input:

> Myevmyozrtilets gwaaarkmv yuozub ubpi farfokm ctbhpe pientsfiydqe. zBmuvtk tahgelyu anlpsmo ttzevagrk yioquj awpyaoryts.

Expected output:

> Memories warm you up from the inside. But they also tear you apart.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide sample inputs, expected outputs, and any codes for your current attempts (to provide context of what you are trying to do and/or what you already tried).

Comment: By default `split()` doesn't affect punctuation

Comment: this has to be a duplicate

Comment: @GinoMempin i added the inputs and outputs, there is no use for adding what code i had by now, because it is wrong

Comment: seeing why your split solution didn't work will surely be useful

Comment: Python doesn't have a concept of "sentence", which at its most basic can be described as a sequence of words (which Python *also* has no concept of). What you *can* do is first produce a list of strings using `str.split`, apply slicing to each resulting string, then join the list of new words back into a single string with `' '.join`. Whether this kind of simple string manipulation corresponds to your definition of "sentence" and "words" is another matter.

Comment: @GinoMempin that is correct

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample implementation below.

Takes in consideration the punctuation (it looks like you've got it apart of the whitespace).

You'd enjoy trying to implement it on your own, I'm sure.

```
f="Myevmyozrtilets gwaaarkmv yuozub ubpi farfokm ctbhpe pientsfiydqe. zBmuvtk tahgelyu anlpsmo ttzevagrk yioquj awpyaoryts."

def g(f):
    c=0
    for l in f:
        if l not in string.ascii_letters:
            yield l
        else:
            if c%2==0:
                yield l
            c+=1


''.join(g(f))
'Memories warm you up from the inside. But they also tear you apart.'
```